# Create xml-attribute with namespace programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

How can I create the following as `XElement`?

```
<data name="MyKey" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Date of birth</value>
    <comment>Some comment</comment>
</data>
```

It throws

> "The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name."

```
var data = new XElement("data");

data.Add(new XAttribute("name", translation.Key));
data.Add(new XAttribute("xml:space", "preserve")); // <-- here is the error

data.Add(new XElement("value") { Value = "Date of birth" });
data.Add(new XElement("comment") { Value = "Some comment" });
```

As this is part of a `ResX`-file, there will be many such `<data></data>`-elements.

Answer (score 5):

Separate the namespace from the local name, using the `XName +(XNamespace, string)` operator for convenience:

```
data.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"));
```

Note that you can write the whole of your element creation in a single go rather more simply:

```
var data = new XElement("data",
    new XAttribute("name", "MyKey"),
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve"),
    new XElement("value", "Date of birth"),
    new XElement("comment", "Some comment")
);
```

Comment: Oh my... That was easy. Thanks also for the "single-creation" hint.